# How to simultaneously change textField.text in a prototype cell?

Tags: swift, uikit, uitextfield, textfield, uitextfielddelegate

I have a UITableViewController and a Prototype cell with a UITextField. When I change a textField.text in one of the cells I want it to be changed in all other cells which my tableView now have (for example multiply number by 2 and set to other cell's textField.text output).

This is the behaviour I want to implement: [CLICK](https://cln.sh/xjw5Od)

Should I trigger a certain textField delegate method or it should be made in another way?

My code for now:

```
 override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
  cell.numberTextField.delegate = self
 }

//Delegate methods

func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    textField.text = ""
    textField.textColor = UIColor.systemBlue
}

func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField, reason: UITextField.DidEndEditingReason) {
        textField.text = "0"
        textField.textColor = UIColor.black
}
```

Comment: you should store variable of the value you want all textfields to have somewhere. Then in a textfield delegate `textFieldDidChangeSelection` you can reload your tableview. In `cellForRowAt indexPath` you need to set the label of the cell's text to the variable. Give this a try, if you cannot figure it out, I can try to prepare an example.

Comment: Hi Shawn, thank you very much. Let me clarify a little bit: I don't want it to store for all my cells, I want it to be set for all other cells except the one I am editing now. So if you check my video I posted, when user clicks on one cell, gives it a value and other cell is changing it's textField output to another value after calculation. I would be so grateful if you can show me example for: input 10 from keyboard for a cell, then other cells as soon as I typed 10 print 20 (multiple by 2). The editing cell is still should show 10.

Comment: Hello, ok I understand you better now. However, some question. Can the user scroll the tableview or there are just few cells without scroll ? Because if there is scroll, then even rows after the scroll should be changed by current cell. Also, does the user only edit the first row or user can edit textfield in any other row ?

Comment: Thank you Shawn. Appreciate your help. Yes, user can scroll tableView, insert and delete cells from it. And user can edit any cell's textField. For example I have added a 3 cells with currency USD, EUR, RUB. Then I change textField for RUB cell on 10. Then I expect USD and EUR to display calculated values based on RUB input. Then I can pick USD and set its value to 5, the rest cells should change its textField values accordingly and so on. I can add as many currencies to tableView as I want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At a high level:

1. You need to have a model to store your data being updated
2. You need to observe the text being entered using `UITextFieldDelegate`
3. As your text is being entered, update all rows except active cell with new calculations

The most interesting work is in `textFieldDidChangeSelection` and `cellForRowAt indexPath`

Here is an example of how I would do something like this:

**1. Set up some custom types**

```
// Your model to store data in text fields
// Maybe for you, you will store currencies
// and base currency to multiply against
// I am just storing a random number for example
struct FinanceModel
{
    var number: Int?
}

// Custom UITextField which will store info
// about cell index path as we need to identify
// it when editing
class MappedTextField: UITextField
{
    var indexPath: IndexPath!
}
```

**2. Example of UITableView Cell, you can ignore if you have your own**

```
fileprivate class CustomCell: UITableViewCell
{
    // Use custom text field
    var textField: MappedTextField!
    
    static let tableViewCellIdentifier = "cell"
    
    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle,
                  reuseIdentifier: String?)
    {
        super.init(style: style,
                   reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        
        configureTextField()
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder)
    {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    // Configure text field and auto layout
    private func configureTextField()
    {
        textField = MappedTextField()
        textField.keyboardType = .numberPad
        textField.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        contentView.addSubview(textField)
        
        textField.layer.borderWidth = 2.0
        textField.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
        textField.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0
        
        // auto-layout
        textField.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor,
                                           constant: 20).isActive = true
        textField.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor,
                                            constant: -20).isActive = true
        textField.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor,
                                       constant: 20).isActive = true
        textField.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor,
                                          constant: -20).isActive = true
    }
}
```

**3. Set up in view controller - you can skip if already set up, just here for completeness**

```
class InputViewController: UIViewController
{
    let tableView = UITableView()
    
    // Initialize your mode
    var financeModel = FinanceModel()
    
    // This will store current editing cell which is active
    var activeTextFieldIndexPath: IndexPath?
    
    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        // This is just view set up for me,
        // You can ignore this
        title = "TableView Input"
        navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = .white
        view.backgroundColor = .white
        
        configureTableView()
    }
    
    // Configure TableView and layout
    private func configureTableView()
    {
        tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        tableView.register(CustomCell.self,
                           forCellReuseIdentifier: CustomCell.tableViewCellIdentifier)
        
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.delegate = self
        
        // remove additional rows
        tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()
        
        view.addSubview(tableView)
        
        // Auto layout
        tableView.leadingAnchor
            .constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        tableView.topAnchor
            .constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor).isActive = true
        tableView.trailingAnchor
            .constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        tableView.bottomAnchor
            .constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    }
}
```

**4. TableView DataSource**

```
extension InputViewController: UITableViewDataSource
{
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,
                   numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
        // Random number for me
        return 10
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,
                   cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
        let cell =
            tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:
                                            CustomCell.tableViewCellIdentifier)
            as! CustomCell
        
        // Set index path of custom text field
        cell.textField.indexPath = indexPath
        
        // Set view controller to respond to text field events
        cell.textField.delegate = self
        
        // Check if any cell is currently active
        // && if we are current cell is NOT the active one
        // We want to leave active cell untouched
        if let activeTextFieldIndexPath = activeTextFieldIndexPath,
           activeTextFieldIndexPath.row != indexPath.row
        {
            updateCell(cell, atIndexPath: indexPath)
        }
        else
        {
            // no active cell, just set the text
            updateCell(cell, atIndexPath: indexPath)
        }

        return cell
    }
    
    private func updateCell(_ cell: CustomCell,
                            atIndexPath indexPath: IndexPath)
    {
        // Retrieve number currently stored in model
        if let number = financeModel.number
        {
            // Set text of number in model * row number
            // Do any calculation you like, this is just an
            // example
            cell.textField.text =
                "\(number) x \(indexPath.row) = \(number * indexPath.row)"
        }
        else
        {
            // If no valid number, set blank
            cell.textField.text = ""
        }
    }
}
```

**5. TextField Delegate**

```
extension InputViewController: UITextFieldDelegate
{
    // Respond to new text in the text field
    func textFieldDidChangeSelection(_ textField: UITextField)
    {
        // 1. Convert generic UITextField to MappedTextField
        // 2. && Retrieve index path from custom MappedTextField
        // 3. && Retrieve text from the text field
        // 4. && Check if text is valid number
        if let textField = textField as? MappedTextField,
           let indexPath = textField.indexPath,
           let text = textField.text,
           let number = Int(text)
        {
            // Assign local variable with index path we are editing
            activeTextFieldIndexPath = indexPath
            
            // Update number in the financial model
            financeModel.number = number
            
            // We only want to update data in visible rows so
            // get all the index paths of visible rows
            let visibleRows = self.tableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows ?? []
            
            // We want to update all rows EXCEPT active row
            // so do a filter for this
            let allRowsWithoutActive = (visibleRows).filter
            {
                    // Remove the active index path from the
                    // visible index paths
                    $0.section != indexPath.section ||
                        $0.row != indexPath.row
            }
            
            // Reload the visible rows EXCEPT active
            self.tableView.reloadRows(at: allRowsWithoutActive,
                                      with: .automatic)
        }
    }
    
    // This is just to make current text field
    // empty when editing, you can ignore
    func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField)
    {
        textField.text = ""
    }
    
    // Reset when text field is no longer being edited
    func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField)
    {
        activeTextFieldIndexPath = nil
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

**6. TableView Delegate**

```
extension InputViewController: UITableViewDelegate
{
    func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView)
    {
        // End editing when scrolling table view
        // This is for me, you can have another way
        view.endEditing(true)
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,
                   heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat
    {
        // Return a random height
        return 80
    }
}
```

End result is something like this:

[image: Update all multiple text fields in UITableView Cell when typing UITableViewCell UITextFieldDelegate]

Hope this gives you enough to set you on your way.

Comment: Thank you very much, Shawn. There is more that enough for me to implement desired behaviour! Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

inside your `textFieldDidBeginEditing` and `textFieldDidChangeSelection` delegates, call `tableView.reloadData()`

Comment: Hi Mahyar. Thank you for the answer. Your suggestion didn't give me the desired result...